# Naming convention for models that get posted against a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, naming-conventions

We use the term *ViewModel* for classes that get returned from a controller and are passed to the view. Instead of using ViewBag or ViewData, we are using a strongly typed class which basically stores every value the view needs.

```
public IActionResult OrderStep1()
{
    var model = new ViewModelStep1()
    {
      SomeProperty = "SomeValue",
       ...
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

I'm looking for a naming convention that specifies how we should name a class that contains the properties that are posted from the submit button of a form to the controller. In the following example, I've chosen `OrderStep2` as a temporary name for that class.

For our multiple step order wizard, we are using [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. Therefore, I can enrich the information from `OrderStep2` and return a specific ViewModel `OrderStep2VM`.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("order/step2")]
public async Task<IActionResult> OrderStep2(OrderStep2 model)
{
  // save some changes into the database and retrieve a GUID configurationId
 return RedirectToAction(nameof(OrderStep2()), new { configurationId = "GUID" });
}

[Route("order/step2/{configurationId}")]
public IActionResult OrderStep2(Guid configurationId)
{
   // retrieve configuration from database based on the configurationID
   // do something else
   var model = new OrderStep2VM()
   {
      ....
   };
   return View(model);
}
```

Since I want the code to be well organized, I'd like to group classes such as `OrderStep2` into a seperate namespace. Currently, I'm thinking of calling them *PostModels*, i.e., `OrderStep2PM`, but I don't want to define a new term for something that probably already exists.

(In case you are wondering why I'm not using TempData: The workflow of the application requires saving incomplete form data which allows me to skip TempData since I need to store in the database anyway).

Comment: Isnt it sufficient to use the same type for both the get/post of OrderStep2?

Comment: This is something I'm currently struggeling with as well. Maybe I actually do need to share the same properties in case I want to also repopulate a previous step from a wizard. I think I can't find a naming convention since my approach probably doesn't make sense to have seperate model classes. hmm

Comment: I guess I'll keep the post available for another couple of hours and delete it in case I realise that I should in fact just use the same models. I think I'm confused since I have a multi-step wizard.

Comment: If the `OrderStep2` type is a domain model I would avoid using it as a binding model.

Comment: No, `OrderStep2` only contains values that should be posted and is not a domain model. Since I want to the asp-for tag helper for form elements, I guess I need to include every property I want to post/submit into the ViewModel as well. So `OrderStep2VM` would include all properties from `OrderStep3PM`. Sorry for my confusion :-|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simply, the model you send to the view should be the same model you get back from the view. Therefore, if you're using `ViewModelStep1` then that's what you should be binding to in the post action, as well.

The term "view model" is stolen from MVVM (model-view-view model), as it serves a similar purpose in MVC as the view model in MVVM. If you don't like the fact that the model you're binding to from your post is called a "view model", then you can simply use something more generic like "DTO" (data transfer object), which works both in the context of model binding and providing data for a view.

Long and short, there are no hard and fast rules here. Name your classes whatever makes the most sense. The names aren't magic. However, whatever you name the class, you'll use the same for both your view model and your binding model.